# Unable to connect to SMTP server 421 connect error 1460

Tags: networking, email, microsoft-outlook, smtp

I have a 2mbps ADSL connection with MWeb on a new account and separately, I got a free 1GB capped account with Axxess some time ago.

When connected to MWeb's network, I'm not able to connect to any SMTP server via Outlook or telnet or any SMTP server, except MWeb's.
I can, however, connect to any SMTP server when I'm connected using my Axxess account.

MWeb have assured me that they're not blocking anything to do with email but the fact remains I can't use my SMTP server when connected to their network.

An attempt to telnet into vodamail's SMTP server (solely to test the connection) yields the following:

> Microsoft Telnet> open smtp.vodamail.co.za 25
> Connecting to smtp.vodamail.co.za...
>
> 421 Cannot connect to SMTP server 196.11.146.149 <196.11.146.149:25>,
> NB connect error 1460
>
> Connection to host lost.
>
> Press any key to continue...

I would be happy to substitute MWeb's SMTP server in my mail setup, however, there are problems with that to do with SMTP relays I believe. See below:

> This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
>
> A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:
>
> support@afrihost.com
> SMTP error from remote mail server after end of
> data:
> host mail.ucebox.co.za [197.242.152.131]: 550 196.35.198.21 is not allowed to send mail from loganyoung.za.net.

Comment: Are you running any anti-virus that is disabling port 25? Can you adjust your outgoing port to something else? My ISP disallows 25, but allows 2525 as a custom configuration.

Comment: @sunk818 I saw something about Avast Antivirus messing with port 25 but I'm not sure how to change that. Also, if my Antivirus was messing with anything, connections to SMTP servers wouldn't work on the Axxess network

Comment: Sounds like MWeb is only allowing SMTP within their network, but not out. Perhaps their explanation is incomplete and misleading. Can Axxess provide you a different port to send SMTP? That might bypass MWeb's restriction (assuming they are restricting on port level, and not packet traffic).